# Почему алгоритм сортировки работает не так, если я вызываю его через метод?

Tags: java

```
package WorkSpace;
import Edition.Array;
import java.util.*;



public class WorkSpace { 
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("кол-во эл-ов массива: ");
        int scan_Number = scan.nextInt(); 

        int[] box1 = new int[scan_Number];        

        Array.array_Add(box1);     

        Array.array_Sort(box1);

    }
}
```

а следующий код из другой папки, но проблема не в модификаторах, т. к. он
все видеит. просто когда я делаю через метод, то все плохо, а если я
пишу все в main(), то все хорошо.

```
package Edition;


public class Array{
    //СОРТИРОВКА массива
    public static void array_Sort(int[] array){

        boolean bool = false;        
        while (!bool){
            for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
                bool = true;
                if(array[i]>array[i+1]){                    
                    bool=false;                    
                    int tmp = array[i];
                    array[i]=array[i+1];
                    array[i+1]=tmp;
                }
            }                
        } 
        //ВЫВОД массива
        for(int i: array){
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

        //ЗАПИСЬ массива
    public static void array_Add(int[] array){        
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length;i++){
            array[i]=(int)(Math.random()*(9+1)+1);                      
        }

        for(int i: array){
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что алгоритм сортировки не работает. Достаточно, чтобы в конце массива стояли два возрастающих элемента, чтобы цикл прекратился, а все предыдущие элементы останутся неотсортированными.

Answer (score 0):

У вас из цикла выходит раньше чем нужно:

```
boolean flag = true;   
int temp;   

while (flag) {
    flag = false;    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) { 
            temp = array[i];         
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
            flag = true;  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотели сделать что-то похожее на пузырьковую сортировку, но ваш цикл работает всего один раз, так как наибольший элемент относится в конец цикла в первой итерации, и на следующей итерации в конце массива два элемента всегда идут по возрастанию, из-за чего `bool = false`, и цикл прекращается.

Пузырьковая сортировка выглядит так:

```java
for (int stop = array.length - 1; stop > 0; stop--)
    for (int i = 0; i < stop; i++)
        if(array[i] > array[i+1]) {
            int tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i+1];
            array[i+1] = tmp;
        }
```